# Search documents by multiple words query in Solr

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have the documents

```
[
  { "id": 1, "title": "next notebook" },
  { "id": 2, "title": "next thing" }
]
```

The `title` field type is

```
<fieldType name="managed_en" positionIncrementGap="100" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="english" />
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory" managed="english" />
    <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/> <!-- required on index analyzers after graph filters -->
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="english" />
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory" managed="english" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And I am trying to search `next thing`, so the request is `/select?q=title%20next%20thing`

I expect that document with `id: 2` will be on top, but the order is same as they were added, and the score is the same `0.3979403`

How should be the query to achieve that if more words from query are in the title, than the document shoud be in the top?

Comment: What is the analyzer for title and score for both the documents?

Comment: @Gibbs I've updated the question

Comment: Do you have any synonyms matching for the given set of three words?

Comment: Yes, I have synonyms only for `notebook, laptop`

Comment: Generally more words match will come at the top. Something is missing I believe.

Comment: It only works if I send `/select?q=title:next title:thing` but i am not sure if it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query is searching the default search field (df) for title, next, and thing %20 is a space character.

q=title%20next%20thing

try something like q=next%20thing&df=title

Comment: It works, thanks, Will it work also for multiple fields?

Comment: Look up edismax queries

Answer (score 1):

Your query considered as `OR` on the default field.

```
q:next thing
```

As you mentioned in the comment, you have to specify the field. Otherwise you can provide list of default fields where your search terms should be looked for.

```
q=title:next thing
```

Both ways are correct. If you have a specific field to search for, you should mention it. Otherwise to search on default field, you can leave the name optional.